# How to Convert JSON to CSV?

Tags: go

How can I fix the error?

http://play.golang.org/p/0UMnUZOUHw

```
// JSON to CSV in Golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

type Json struct {
    RecordID int64  `json:"recordId"`
    DOJ      string `json:"Date of joining"`
    EmpID    string `json:"Employee ID"`
}

func main() {
    // reading data from JSON File
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./people.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    // Unmarshal JSON data
    var d []Json
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &d)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    // Create a csv file
    f, _ := os.Create("./people.csv")
    defer f.Close()
    // Write Unmarshaled json data to CSV file
    w := csv.NewWriter(f)

    // How to proceed further?
    /* I am getting errors if i use below
    for _,obj := range d {
      var record []interface{}
      record = append(record, obj.RecordID)
      record = append(record, obj.DOJ)
      record = append(record, obj.EmpID)
      w.Write(record)
    }
    */
}
```

Error:

```
cannot use record (type []interface {}) as type []string in function argument
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code inline in your question. And "can anyone help" isn't a good question here. What exactly is your problem? Errors? Not doing what you want? Please [edit] your question with the code and much more information about your actual problem.

Comment: Please post your intentions and expectations. Please post what it was you saw that contradicted your expectations. Please ask a specific question. Please post the exact line(s) you are having trouble with. As it stands; your question will be closed.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

type Json struct {
    RecordID int64  `json:"recordId"`
    DOJ      string `json:"Date of joining"`
    EmpID    string `json:"Employee ID"`
}

func main() {
    // reading data from JSON File
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./people.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    // Unmarshal JSON data
    var d []Json
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &d)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    // Create a csv file
    f, err := os.Create("./people.csv")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    // Write Unmarshaled json data to CSV file
    w := csv.NewWriter(f)
    for _, obj := range d {
        var record []string
        record = append(record, strconv.FormatInt(obj.RecordID, 10))
        record = append(record, obj.DOJ)
        record = append(record, obj.EmpID)
        w.Write(record)
    }
    w.Flush()
}
```

Comment: looks good, only one suggestion for improvement: as of performance state of mind it is better to use only one `append` something like this:  `record = append(record, strconv.FormatInt(obj.RecordID, 10), obj.DOJ, obj.EmpID) `

Comment: Actually, there is a problem here. You have to clear slice after writing. Otherwise, it will append elements continuously.
Use "record = nil" after  w.Write(record)

Answer (score 1):

csv Writer's [`Write`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#Writer.Write) does not expect an `[]interface{}` it expects a `[]string`.